# Voltage divider, Zener diode versus resistor

Tags: diodes, voltage-divider

I came across this schematic and I am wondering, how does it compare to a voltage divider based on two resistors. I'm trying to find the reasoning for using a Zener diode in this configuration. I know the voltage across the diode will be constant but I cannot figure out why that would provide an advantage here.

- The resistor is a 220 Ω resistor.
- The diode is a 10 V Zener diode.
- Voltage division between diode and resistor is connected to an STM32 for reading a voltage value in the STM32.

IC1 is a current sensor (tmcs1101a4bqdrq1) sensing current over a 12 V line.

[image: The schematic, sorry not a clean drawing]

Comment: What is the purpose of this circuit?

Comment: Seems like a circuit designed for the purpose of frying microcontrollers?

Comment: @Lundin could you explain your observation? :) I mean, I would like to know more in deapth how so/ why so

Comment: Ok so it might just be badly drawn. I peeked at the IC and it's a hall effect sensor. Meaning maybe there's no connection between the 12V and the MCU? The signal towards the MCU should be Vout not In- and not both at once. Please draw proper schematics so there's no guessing involved. Either way you shouldn't hand over 10V to a MCU in any given scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how does it compare to a voltage divider based on two resistors. I'm
> trying to find the reasoning for using a Zener diode in this
> configuration.*

It does work but, not as a voltage divider; it works as a voltage subtractor <-- 10 volts (the Zener voltage) is subtracted from the 12 volt supply and it leaves 2 volts across the 220 Ω resistor. That 2 volts is presumably attached to an analogue input pin on the MCU.

The benefit of a subtractor is that any moderate change in the 12 volt level is seen as the same voltage change by the MCU. If you were to use a resistive divider to convert 12 volts to 2 volts, any changes on the 12 volts would be 6:1 attenuated on the MCU input. That doesn't sound like a big deal to me but maybe the designer had some reason for using a voltage subtractor rather than a divider.

Clearly, with the Zener circuit, if the supply dropped to 11 volts or rose to 13 volts the MCU would see a +/- 1 volt change at its input pin. Maybe this is important to the designer. Using a 6:1 resistive divider would result in a change of +/- 166.7 mV.

As a precaution against unforeseen circumstances I'd want to add a current limit resistor in series with the MCU input; maybe 10 kΩ.

Comment: Do you think it's viable to use _(even)_ a precision Zener diode over a circuit that shapes the signal with an op-amp? E.g. [BZT585B10T](https://www.mouser.ch/pdfdocs/BZT585BxVxT.PDF): [Vz Min/Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc0Iq.png) seems too unprecise for this purpose. Or would you use a shunt regulator (e.g. [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl432li-q1.pdf)) instead?

Comment: @Velvel I have no real idea why the designer of the circuit in the question used a Zener diode because modern day ADCs have enough resolution to use a simpler (and more accurate) resistive divider. So, unless there is a compelling reason to use the Zener diode circuit, I would not use it.

Answer (score 1):

Powering an MCU from any sort of a divider rather than a voltage regulator is problematic. Linear voltage regulators are made in such big numbers that they cost about as much as a discrete transistor in small quantities.

I’ve used a divider voltage source to bootstrap an MCU start up when the MCU itself was controlling the switching converter, in a cost-critical circuit. It’d start up in low power mode from the divider, start switching the converter switch, its output would “overpower” the divider, transitioning to the switcher output, and fully power up then.

It’s acceptable in some tightly controlled circumstances, eg. when running from a 5V VBUS from a USB upstream-facing port that’s not USB-C. With USB-C, you have to assume that someone will plug in 20V on VBUS and the device must protect itself from it.

When using “loosely specified” external supplies that are expected to have big voltage tolerances, it’s best to just use a series regulator - like any LDO. There’s very little benefit to using a shunt regulator or a divider then, unless you’re saving cents off the cost. A TL431 is not a bad part, but there are way better LDOs that cost same or less!